# Delete a node with multiple fields in a single Linked List recursively in C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm trying to delete all nodes of users having an age that is less than the given limit. Problem is this function's implementation is incorrect. The algorithm must be recursive.

Input Example:

```
Jennifer 11
John 19
Sarah 17
Mark 24
```

Output example:

```
(null) 11
John 19
 17
Mark 24
```

Here is the code:

```
struct list *delete_node(struct list *l, int limit) {
    if (l != NULL) {
        if (l->age < limit) {
            struct list *tmp;
            tmp = l->next;
            free(l);
        }
        if (l->next != NULL)
            l->next = delete_node(l->next, limit);
        else
            return l;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why must it be recursive? I would rather write this as a loop that iterates through all elements of the list, removing those that match the criteria.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Because it's a homework

Comment: @G.Sliepen I would prefer it to write iteratively as well hahaha

Comment: You set `tmp = l->next`, but then you never do anything with `tmp` anymore. Also, `return list` will not compile, you probably meant `return l`. Also think of whether this should be in the `else` branch or somewhere else.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Sorry I forgot to edit return list (it's a typo), in my  standard delete_node algorithm I have a return tmp after freeing l, but now I can't use it because if I return tmp it will (successfully) delete just the first user matched. I need to delete em all so I thought removing return tmp would have been a good idea but it isn't.

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to your question. Marking an answer as accepted is enough to convey that the question has been solved. I have reverted your edit.

Comment: A recursive implementation is only OK if it is a requirement. Otherwise a long enough list will cause a **stack overflow** because the number of recursive calls is proportional to the list length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the code is missing one line, noted in comment:

```
    if (l->age < limit){
        struct list* tmp;
        tmp = l->next;
        free(l);
        l = tmp;                   // fix
    }
```

As answered by "chqrlie for yellow blockquotes", there other problems, which he has fixed in his answer. You commented that it was solved, but I don't know if your fixed code handles all cases (first node, last node, adjacent nodes, ...). You could update your question with the complete solved code.

Comment: Solved! Thanks a lot!

Comment: NO, not solved! the function does not return anything after the recursive call. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: @rcgldr: I'm afraid your version does not remove consecutive matching nodes.

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes - I copy/pasted the wrong version before I did a permutation like test for all cases. I ended up with essentially the same code as you, except I didn't use braces on the else. I updated my answer to refer to your answer. You got an upvote from me. We still don't know what the OP ended up doing. A commented before (and now deleted), I was planning on fixing one problem at a time, waiting for interaction with the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your function has multiple problems:

- you do not return anything if `l` is `NULL` nor if `l->next` is `NULL`.
- `l` is invalid after deleting a node. You should return `delete_node(tmp, limit)` after the `free(l);`. To have a single `return` statement, you can set `l` to this value.

Here is a modified version:

```c
struct list *delete_node(struct list *l, int limit) {
    if (l != NULL) {
        if (l->age < limit) {
            struct list *tmp;
            tmp = l->next;
            free(l);
            l = delete_node(tmp, limit);
        } else {
            l->next = delete_mode(l->next, limit);
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function has undefined behavior because it returns nothing in the case when `l->next` is not equal to `NULL`.

```
//...
if (l->next != NULL)
    l->next = delete_node (l->next, limit);
else
    return l;
}
```

Also in this code snippet

```
if (l->age < limit){
    struct list* tmp;
    tmp = l->next;
    free(l);
}
```

the pointer `l` has an invalid value after deleting the pointed memory.

The function can be implemented the following way

```
struct list * delete_node( struct list *l, int limit )
{
    if ( l != NULL )
    {
        if ( l->age < limit )
        {
            struct list *tmp = l;
            l = l->next;
            free( tmp );
            l = delete_node( l, limit );
        }
        else
        {
            l->next = delete_node( l->next, limit );
        }
    }

    return l;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program. The function that displays the list is also written as a recursive function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct list
{
    int age;
    struct list *next;
};

struct list * delete_node( struct list *l, int limit )
{
    if ( l != NULL )
    {
        if ( l->age < limit )
        {
            struct list *tmp = l;
            l = l->next;
            free( tmp );
            l = delete_node( l, limit );
        }
        else
        {
            l->next = delete_node( l->next, limit );
        }
    }

    return l;
}

void display( struct list *l )
{
    if ( l == NULL )
    {
        puts( "null" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", l->age );
        display( l->next );
    }
}

int push_front( struct list **l, int age )
{
    struct list *current = malloc( sizeof( struct list ) );
    int success = current != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        current->age = age;
        current->next = *l;
        *l = current;
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { Lower = 7, Upper = 20 };

    struct list *head = NULL;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( int i = Lower; i < Upper; ++i )
    {
        int age = rand() % ( Upper - Lower + 1 ) + Lower;
        push_front( &head, age );
    }

    display( head );

    head = delete_node( head, ( Upper + Lower ) / 2 );

    display( head );

    head = delete_node( head, Upper + 1 );

    display( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
14 -> 11 -> 8 -> 15 -> 8 -> 13 -> 16 -> 18 -> 11 -> 8 -> 18 -> 13 -> 12 -> null
14 -> 15 -> 13 -> 16 -> 18 -> 18 -> 13 -> null
null
```

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes I was preparing a demonstrative program to be sure that the function definition is correct.